# Delete item in listview and then refresh it

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences, android-viewholder

I have the following code that implements a button that removes an item in a listview. I use a sharedpreferences variable to store values (url) that points to images displayed in the listview. Each image has this button that lets to remove it from the listview:

```
viewHolder.buttonHolderBorrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SharedPreferences.Editor prefsTH = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PrefsTH", ListadoImagenesSubidasMain.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            prefsTH.remove("urlTH"+posicion);
            prefsTH.commit();
            SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext).edit();
            sharedPreferences.remove("url" + posicion);
            sharedPreferences.commit();

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

I guess that notifyDataSetChanged updates the listview and redraw it again after pressing the button. What do I have to do to refresh the listview in this case?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Unless you access the SharedPreferences every time the adapter needs data(like the getCount() or getView()) methods which would be wasteful, you need to delete the item from the list on which the adapter is actually based.

Comment: could you post an example please?

Comment: Better post your adapter's code.